# How can I submit this form with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, frame, webdriverwait

I've been trying to make a Python script to login into a certain website, navigate through the menu, fill out a form and save the file it generates to a folder.

I am having some problems to submit the form.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://directa.natal.rn.gov.br/")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='mainsystem'][src^='main']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input[name='usuario']"))).send_keys("11844691000126")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input[name='senha']").send_keys("Link2007")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn[name='acessar']").click()
```

Comment: _I am having some problems to submit de form_ Explain the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fill up the required fields then to *submit* the form you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://directa.natal.rn.gov.br/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='mainsystem'][src^='main']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input[name='usuario']"))).send_keys("11844691000126")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input[name='senha']").send_keys("Link2007")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn#acessar").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: directa]

Comment: Thank you! It is not working on Chrome, but it is working on Firefox. I dont Know why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to the iframe, because your element is not in the main website, is inside iframe.

```
iframes = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='mainsystem']")
print("Iframes: %s" %len(iframes))
browser.switch_to_frame(iframes[0])
```